# How can I have two editors for the same property on a switch?

Tags: gwt, gwt-editors

I am trying to create an editor where the user can either select an existing item or create a new one inline. For example, imagine the typical person-address relationship. I want a form where the user, when editing a person, can either select an address from a set of existing addresses or create a new address without moving to a separate form.

Naively, this seems to require two different editors for the same property. Say I have a `Person` which has `Address getAddress()` and `setAddress(Address)`. My `PersonEditor` class would need to have two sub-editors named `address` of differing types; one to select an existing person and the another a composite of editors to descend into the `Address` type and allow editing of its properties.

From reading the documentation on [`CompositeEditor`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/editor/client/CompositeEditor.html), it seems like I have to make use of it to dynamically select the sub-editor. However, the documentation isn't detailed enough for me to really understand how I should implement the interface. I've tried looking at how [`ListEditor`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/editor/client/adapters/ListEditor.html) and `OptionalFieldEditor` are implemented for clues, but to avail. `ListEditor` doesn't seem like a straight fit as my sub-editors edit different paths.

For instance, trying to use `CompositeEditor`, I'm unclear on what `createEditorForTraversal` and `getPathElement` should return in my case.

How do I dynamically attach one of two *different* types of editors to one property?

Comment: You really need to edit your question to provide a more simpler question and attach a code snippet on what you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this in the end. I simply added two editors with the same `@Path` annotation. I was not expecting the editor framework to allow this, but it seems to work!